# Butterknife: temporarily disable listener

Tags: android, butterknife

I set `@OnClick` listener to a view in a list item. In some cases I need to disable the listener for this view so that the list view can handle the click (OnItemClickListener should be called), and then enable it again. Is there a way to do this with Butterknife?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked through the ButterKnife sources and it looks like BK generates and sets `OnClickListener`s on views when you're using `@OnClick(R.id.some_id)` annotation.

Now, the only way to disable `OnClickListener` is to remove it:

`item.setOnClickListener(null)`.

If you need it again, you can ask `ButterKnife` to repeat the injection:

`ButterKnife.inject(item);`

That and the solution proposed by Ethan are the only solutions I can think of.

Comment: Seems a bit awkward, but for a lack of more elegant solution this will do. Thanks!

Comment: In [version 7.0.0](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-700-2015-06-27) `inject` was replaced by `bind`.

Comment: @aga : I am trying to do this for ImageView. Unable to set the OnClickListener again using `ButterKnife.bind(myImageView)`

Answer (score 2):

With Butterknife I don't know. But I know you can do this by creating a private boolean and an if statement. `if(yourboolean == true){ //set your onClickListener }else{//do nothing }`

Comment: If I do this in view listener, parent listener is not called.

Comment: Then call parent listener manually from within this 'if()' statement

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but it feels like workaround. Also, there's the case when parent is a list view item and listener is set for ListView (updated my question to reflect this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean flag like `shouldListenClick` in the app and set to true and false where ever you wish. Then, you can check the `shouldListenClick` in the `@OnClick` or any other ButterKnife listener call before executing its code.